# Using ZTIWindowsUpdates.wsf to apply WSUS patches (outside MDT)

Tags: wsus

I have a need to apply Microsoft patches/hotfixes from a WSUS server. I'm already using `ZTIWindowsUpdate.wsf` in my stand-alone MDT environment to patch machines during the build.

My target machines are not currently managed by SCCM.

Can this script be used to pull hotfixes on-demand (outside MDT) from a WSUS server? If so, is there a specific syntax? If not, are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out and came up with my own script which includes some corner cases. I used the following script as reference:

- **`ZTIWindowsUpdate.wsf` from MDT 2012 Update 1**

  Used as reference for registry settings to point to proper WSUS server before search, download and install operations are started.

The following scripts used for reference for the main operation.

- **`wsusupdate.vbs`**

  http://www.cms.waikato.ac.nz/~harry/wsusupdate.vbs
- **`CheckUpdate.vbs`**

  http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/VB-Script-to-Check-and-620579cd